# Angular ag grid individual row collapse on button click

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I need to collapse a expanded row in ag grid using angular. Can someone please help me out on this?
I have tried setExpanded(false); kind using the documentation but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Give a class called **hide** for the html element

Make the display property for the class is none:

```
.hide{display: none}
```

Then go to the element and make class binding:

```
<div [class.hide]="isOpen">Your targeted element</div>
```

Go to the typescript file and create a bool variable called isOpen:

```
isOpen: bool = false;
```

Create a button that has click handler called onClick

```
<button (click)="onClick()"></button>
```

Go to the type script and create onClick function:

```
onClick(){
this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
}
```

Comment: In my case, Ag gid will generate dynamically the rows based server response. I'm not creating the html elements manually, ag-grid will have those elements created/generated when they load on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-model-grouping/#expand-all--collapse-all

Check `node.group`  and `node.level`

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
    if (node.group && node.level == 0) {
        node.setExpanded(false);
    }
});
```